# Disable update for one app on iOS

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, auto-update

How to make one app never update? It's the old Ingress version. New is very bad, even if has some better management things that previous needed, but it's strangely weird.

Comment: Have you written to the developers of this app to register your concerns?

Comment: Did the answer work for you? Apple shortcuts might work for this but I have not tried it. I have apps like this where they break things and take forever to fix then. Or make an change for political purposes that I disagree with, so I don’t want the update.

Answer (score 4):

**You can't disable one app update access**.

You can turn off automatic updates and not update it manually, to turn off automatic updates:

1. Go to Settings
2. iTunes & App Store
3. Find *App Updates* and turn it off